# How to asynchronously updating a label displaying an info

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, label

I'm working in wpf and I need to update an element of the view with a class.
 
So, I have three files:

- MainWindow.xaml -> Where the element I want to update is.
- MainWindow.xaml.cs -> Where I call a function of an other class (utils.cs).
- Utils.cs -> Where we can find the function freeSpace() (this function calculate the free space on the disk), in this function I want to change a label in MainWindow.xaml.

The element I need to change is a label.

Why can't mainwindow's own code behind get a new name from the function and make the change itself? 
I want the calcultation to be done outside of the mainwindow code, in order to have clear code.

My problem in this case is that in Utils.cs I have two functions, copy() and freeSpace(). The copy function copy a file and it calls freeSpace. In free space I have a loop that check every 10 seconds the freeSpace until the copy is finished. So every 10 seconds I need to change the label that represent the free space.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Label x:Name="freeSpaceLabel"></Label>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
   private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Utils u = new Utils();
        u.copy();
    }
```

Utils.cs

```
  private void freeSpace(){
            while (isFinish())
            {
                 // Update the label    
                  [...] 
                  drive.TotalFreeSpace; //return an int, I just want to set this int to the label of my view.
                  [...]
                  Thread.Sleep(10000); 
            }
    }

private void isFinish(){
    // Return true if the copy is finish
    // Return false if the copy is not finish
}

private void copy(){
    //Copy a file 
    freeSpace();
}
```

I do not think that passing the view is a good solution.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to make your Task Asyncrounous:

```
private async void DoyourWorkHere()
{   
  await Task t = Task.Run( () => 
  {
      Utils u = new Utils();
       u.copy();
  } );    
}
```

Call this method from button click.

> For Updating Label:

You can create event and delegate to send info back to your MainWindow or you can send MainWindow as parameter to util class and call a public property from Util class to update your Label

Comment: This is not Asynchronous, it executes on a separate thread pool thread and in fact in this too `Task.Run` is preferred. Also Wait on Task blocks the  main thread, which defeats the purpose

Comment: oh i didnt notice about wait method Edited

Comment: Now it will not stop for task to complete :) and Button start will finish executing, You need Async-Await, as that's the only mechanism to get it done

Comment: The two solutions works, the second problem is that I need to update the view from Utils.cs

Comment: Yes i already thought about that.but Thank you for pointing out the issue

Comment: Though I would prefer `Copy` to be `CopyAsync`, but even now you can `await t`, atleast that will not block the main thread and to an extent purpose is served

Comment: you can create event and delegate to send info back to your MainWindow @ParkPark or you can send MainWindow as parameter to util class and call a public property from Util class to update your Label

Answer (score 0):

You might not need Util.cs at all.

What you need is BackgroundWorker and ProgressChanged. Try this:

**Stack_43489182.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.Test01.Stack_43489182"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.Test01"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Stack_43489182" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnStartAsync" Content="Start Async" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Button_Click" />
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**Stack_43489182.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Wpf.Test01
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Stack_43489182.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Stack_43489182 : Window
    {
        private BackgroundWorker worker;
        public Stack_43489182()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
            this.worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
            this.worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }

        private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            /** you need to put code from Util.cs here **/

            int i = 1;
            while(i <= 10)
            {
                this.worker.ReportProgress((int)((i / (double)10) * 100));

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                i++;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            this.worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

You can even implement cancel to stop your operation.

See this example for using BackgroundWorker:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

**If you need to reuse your Util class then**

**Stack_43489182.xaml.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Wpf.Test01
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Stack_43489182.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Stack_43489182 : Window
    {
        private BackgroundWorker worker;
        private Utils util;

        public Stack_43489182()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
            //this.worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
            this.worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            this.util = new Utils();
            util.FreeSpace_ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
        }

        private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                                       new Action(() => this.progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage));
        }

        private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var utils = e.Argument as Utils;

            if(utils != null)
            {
                utils.copy();
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            this.worker.RunWorkerAsync(util);
        }

        public class Utils
        {
            public event ProgressChangedEventHandler FreeSpace_ProgressChanged;

            private void freeSpace()
            {
                int i = 1;
                while (!isFinished(i))
                {

                    if(FreeSpace_ProgressChanged != null)
                    {
                        FreeSpace_ProgressChanged(i, new ProgressChangedEventArgs((int)((i / 10.0) * 100), null));
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    i++;
                }
            }

            private bool isFinished(int i)
            {
                // Return true if the copy is finish
                // Return false if the copy is not finish
                return i == 10 ? true : false;
            }

            public void copy()
            {
                //Copy a file 
                freeSpace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of copying some code, you shall modify it to solve the code requirement OP has suggested

Comment: I gave an idea for solution. I think some effort should be made by author

Comment: Issue is idea is also outdated, since Async Await does the same job much more efficiently